# Return class instance from class

Tags: c++

I have this code, I want to fill my vector of strings from another class

```
class A
{
  public:
    B foo(const string & name) const;
}

class B
{
  public:
    void Add(const string & name);
    vector<string> list;
}

void B::Add(const string & name)
{
   list.push_back(name);
}

B A::foo(const string & name) const
{
  B tmp;
  tmp.Add(name);
  return tmp;
}
```

I know this doesnt work because tmp gets destructed, but I dont know how to fix it, should i return pointer to tmp in foo()?

Comment: Why does it matter that `tmp` gets destructed?

Comment: _"I know this doesnt work because tmp gets destructed, "_ But it will get copied to the return value before. I can't see a problem with this as long you're returning by value.

Comment: `tmp` is not destructed. It is returned by the function.

Comment: What's the problem? You're returning by value, so `tmp` is copied to the return value before it's destroyed. (Subject to copy elision; but the code is just as valid either way.)

Comment: because then i am pointing to memory that i do not own

Comment: @lodo It will certainly be destructed as soon the function scope ends.

Comment: Nothing's pointing to anything; there are no pointers or references, just a copy of the local variable, made before destroying it.

Comment: @lllook _"because then i am pointing to memory that i do not own"_ Where? Not in your sample code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because of return value optimization, tmp is not destructed but moved to the calling function. Thinking of it as being destroyed is exactly why OP gets confused (even if technically it could be copied and destroyed).

Comment: when i am debugging this nothing happens to tmp tmp.list is empty

Comment: @lllook Show a full minimal code sample here please, that reproduces the behavior you observe.

Comment: @lllook: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/f7GPmW) if I fix the syntax errors and write a simple test case. Perhaps you could post a [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate whatever problem you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know this doesnt work because tmp gets destructed

It's destroyed *after* it's copied to give the function's return value, so there's no problem there. There would be a problem if you returned a pointer or reference to the local variable; but you're not doing that.

> I dont know how to fix it

It's not broken, so there's nothing to fix.

> should i return pointer to `tmp`

No, that would introduce exactly the problem you're thinking of. Returning by value avoids the problem.